# How can I allow editing of Sitecore CMS data to users outside my network?

Tags: sitecore-api

I'm currently working on a project to create a non-commerce product listing site where listings are created and managed by our external partners, who will validate by a different IDP from internal users. My organization uses Sitecore for its main website, so we will be creating the site in Sitecore (headless).

The challenge is to allow our external partners access to

a) create a product listing and submit it for approval and publishing, and

b) access their owned listings for editing and approval submission.

I've been trying to find out the best way to achieve this, but so far without success.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Depending on what the IDP is that the external partners are using, you should be able to add that IDP as an identity sub provider for sitecores own identity server. Once added, those coming from that provider can be identified and assigned a specific domain and role. You can then lock down back end access to page in the usual way using sitecore role based access.

Comment: Thanks for this - would this allow data access in a web content form, or would it need to be access to the CMS itself? We need to restrict permissions to adding / updating content only, which is why we would create a WYSIWYG form surfacing just the relevant data.

Comment: The approach I mention above is purely focused on accessing the CMS itself. The backend of sitecore can be fully locked down as you choose. For example only show content editor, and only one very small branch of content. You can also restrict to add/edit items. I don't have a lot of experience with headless, but think it could be quite tricky to integrate an external idp without using ID server.